# gnuplot: How to determine version of pdf output

Tags: pdf, latex, gnuplot

I export gnuplot as PDF as follows:

```
gnuplot -e "set terminal cairolatex pdf ;set output 'file.tex';load 'file.gp'"
```

Works fine but creates PDF version 1.7.
All other material works with 1.5, so I wonder whether I can reduce to 1.5 also.

Comment: Which operating system and version of gnuplot are you running?

Comment: A pdf file created by gnuplot will get whatever pdf version the cairo library gives by default.  In principle gnuplot could tell the cairo library that it would prefer a specific version, in this case 1.5, but there is no option currently that allows a user to request this.  I agree that it would be useful, and suggest that you submit this as a feature request on the gnuplot issue tracker.

Comment: @Ethan: so I must adapt my tex file: set minor version.. ok, that I wanted to avoid. 
Is known whether there is a feature really needing 1.7?

Comment: @theozh suse tumbleweed, linux, gnuplot 5.4 patchlevel 10

Comment: @KJ I know, just a matter of warning.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a comment rather than an answer but it got too long and I couldn't get the formatting that way...

I appreciate your question because I had been trying to solve a related problem going in the other direction: "How can I get TeX to stop complaining about gnuplot-generated pdf files?".  The best I could figure out was:

```
% Prevent error/warning messages
%  "found PDF version '1.7' but at most version '1.5' allowed"
% Unfortunately this mechanism is specific to pdflatex.
% It can be commented out here to allow use of lualatex or xelatex.
  \pdfinclusionerrorlevel=1
  \pdfminorversion=7
  \pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1
```

Your question made me realize that the better approach is to persuade gnuplot to generate pdf output tagged as version 1.5.   I hacked in a call

```
cairo_pdf_surface_restrict_to_version(surface, CAIRO_PDF_VERSION_1_5);
```

in the gnuplot pdf terminal source to confirm that this would work but I don't have a proper patch yet to check for library version compatibility or to add a user command that selects it.